# Two formulas for the curvature of a planar curve

Tags: euclidean-geometry, curves, curvature

In Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature

There are two formulas for the curvature of a planar curve:

1) parametrically

> For a plane curve given parametrically in [[Cartesian coordinates]] as $ c(t) = ( x(t),y(t)) $  the curvature is
>
> $$ \kappa = \frac{|x'y''-y'x''|}{\left(x'^2+y'^2\right) ^ \frac32}$$
>
> where primes refer to derivatives $ \frac{d}{dt}$ with respect to the parameter $t$.

And 2) Curvature from arc and chord length

> Given two points $P$ and $Q$ on $c$,
>   let $ s(P,Q) $ be the arc length of the portion of the curve between $P$ and $Q$ and 
>   let $ d(P,Q) $ denote the length of the line segment from $P$ and $Q$. 
>   The curvature of $c$ at $P$ is given by the limit
>
> $$ \kappa(P) = \lim_{ Q \to P} \sqrt \frac{24 \big(s(P,Q) -d (P,Q)\big)} {s(P,Q)^3}$$
>
> Where the limit is taken as the point $Q$. approaches $P$ on $c$.
>   The denominator can equally well be taken to be  $ d(P,Q)^3$. 
>   The formula follows by verifying it for the osculating circle.

(my remark: really ?? I did not manage this)

How can the second formula be derrived from the first one? 
(or even from the osculating circle?)

You may even assume the curve $c$ is a circle with radius $r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula could be verified for the osculating circle as follows.
Considering two points $P$ and $Q$ at the extremities of given circular arc of the osculating circle, subtended by an angle $\alpha$, the formula reads:

$$ \kappa (P) = \lim_{Q \to P} \sqrt{ \frac{24 \Big( s(P,Q) - d(P,Q)\Big)}{s(P,Q)^3}} = \\
\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \sqrt{ \frac{24 \Big( \alpha r - 2r \sin{\frac{\alpha}{2} }\Big)}{\alpha^3 r^3}} = \\
\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \sqrt{ \frac{24 \Big( \alpha r - 2r (\frac{\alpha}{2} -\frac{1}{3!}({\frac{\alpha}{2})^3+\dots} \Big)}{\alpha^3 r^3}} = \\
 \sqrt{ \frac{24 \Big(  r \frac{\alpha^3}{24} \Big)}{\alpha^3 r^3}} = \frac{1}{r}
$$

where the Taylor expansion $\sin x \approx x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \dots$ is exploited.

As the linked Wikipedia article points out, the denominator could be substituted by $d(P,Q)^3$ and the same results follows, as it is easy to verify from the above calculation.